# I can't figure out what is wrong with my HTML and jQuery impementation

Tags: html, jquery

I am very new to HTML and jQuery and this is probably a dumb question but, believe me, I have tried everything that makes sense in my mind.

So I am making a website that has been pre-built for my mc server. It uses .twig files which make sense. My goal is to add a button, which when pressed, will copy the server IP to clipboard. I found this code online from this link: https://codepen.io/shaikmaqsood/pen/XmydxJ  and it should work. I copied the HTML button and pasted it into my header file:

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('ip')">IP</button>
```

The jS I tried multiple ways. I tried making a new jS file and using the 
    ''
And also making an actual block:

```
<script>
function copyToClipboard(element) {
   var $temp = $("<input>");
   $("body").append($temp);
   $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
   document.execCommand("copy");
   $temp.remove();
}
</script>
```

However, whenever I click the button, it does not copy anything.
I am defiantly doing something wrong and I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!.

This is what I have:

```
<button id="copyButton" onclick="copyToClipboard()">ip.adress.net</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
let copyButton = document.getElementById("copyButton");

function copyToClipboard() {
    let $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(copyButton.innerText).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
</script>
```

UPDATE:
I tried the Tryit editor and just that code works perfect, however for some reason, it doesn't on my website and I am so lost now...

Comment: A string of `ip` is not a valid selector, unless your page has an `<ip>` tag, which i'm assuming it does not.

Comment: What you show is jQuery. Are you including that library?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have JQuery included somewhere else. And for the other one, I have to make it a selector? I thought I could just put text in there to copy?

Comment: I assume you have `<div id="ip">...</div>` somewhere? For that you need `#ip` as selector.

Comment: `$(element)` is selecting an element on the page.  If you look at that codepen you linked to, your method call to copyToClipboard does not match theirs.

Comment: Ok then that's what it is. Ill make it and see if it works. Again, I don't know much abt JS or HTML and I am just trying to figure it out. I thought it copies the string inside single quotes.

Comment: Is it a fixed IP? If so you can use `$temp.val("the IP").select();` instead. The code you copied without understanding it creates an input element, then fills it with the contents of the element you specified, then selects the copied text. You specified the element by passing a selector of `ip`, but that selector tries to select an HTML element `<ip>`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just use `.innerText` of the element...

Solution-

```
<script>
let copyButton = document.getElementById("copyButton");

function copyToClipboard() {
    let $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(copyButton.innerText).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
</script>
```

---

I've also found a different approach-

```
const copyToClipboard = str => {
        const el = document.createElement('textarea');
        el.value = str;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        el.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(el);
    };
};
```

if you were looking for a different approach, just replace you function with the function above...

---

this was found here- https://www.30secondsofcode.org/blog/s/copy-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript

I hope this helps! good luck on your coding journey

Comment: I tried the .innerText and it works in the Tryit but not on the website. I have no clue whats going on

Answer (score 0):

I think you copied the button code wrong.
Here is how it looks from the tutorial

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy TEXT 1</button>
```

yours is missing the **#** which represents the id of the html element.